# How to send result Intent using onPause (back button)

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, onpause, android-ondestroy

I have an Activity that contains a Recycler view and is called from the main activity with an extra string.  The user would then do some things that would change the string and I would like to send it back to the Main activity.  Is there a way to do this just using the back button on the phone?  I have the result intent setting the result in the "onPause" method of my second activity, but the main activity keeps saying the result was canceled.  Please help!

Main Activity code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                pantryJson = data.getStringExtra("newPantryContents");
                pantry = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(pantryJson,
                        Ingredient[].class)));
                System.out.println("onActivityResult says: " + pantryJson);
                savePantry();
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                System.out.println("onActivityResult says: result canceled");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

my Second Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        String pantryJsonArray = new Gson().toJson(pantry);
        System.out.println("ViewPantry onDestroy says: " + pantryJsonArray);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewPantryActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("newPantryContents",pantryJsonArray);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        String pantryJsonArray = new Gson().toJson(pantry);
        System.out.println("ViewPantry onPause Says" + pantryJsonArray);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ViewPantryActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("newPantryContents",pantryJsonArray);
        setResult(ViewPantryActivity.RESULT_OK,resultIntent);
        super.onPause();

    }
```

LogCat System.Out:

```
2019-11-02 22:05:42.068 566-566/com.example.myapplication I/System.out: ViewPantry onPause Says[{"barcode":{"cornerPoints":[{"x":181,"y":360},{"x":193,"y":356},{"x":193,"y":479},{"x":181,"y":483}],"displayValue":"04904500","format":1024,"rawValue":"04904500","valueFormat":5},"image":{"mHeight":300,"mNativePtr":497431990208,"mWidth":300},"name":"Clicked","quantityInPantry":1},{"barcode":{"cornerPoints":[{"x":157,"y":359},{"x":229,"y":335},{"x":229,"y":461},{"x":157,"y":487}],"displayValue":"04904500","format":1024,"rawValue":"04904500","valueFormat":5},"image":{"mHeight":300,"mNativePtr":497433345344,"mWidth":300},"name":"Diet Coca-cola","quantityInPantry":3}]
2019-11-02 22:05:42.073 566-566/com.example.myapplication I/System.out: onActivityResult says: result canceled
2019-11-02 22:05:42.516 566-566/com.example.myapplication I/System.out: ViewPantry onDestroy says: [{"barcode":{"cornerPoints":[{"x":181,"y":360},{"x":193,"y":356},{"x":193,"y":479},{"x":181,"y":483}],"displayValue":"04904500","format":1024,"rawValue":"04904500","valueFormat":5},"image":{"mHeight":300,"mNativePtr":497431990208,"mWidth":300},"name":"Clicked","quantityInPantry":1},{"barcode":{"cornerPoints":[{"x":157,"y":359},{"x":229,"y":335},{"x":229,"y":461},{"x":157,"y":487}],"displayValue":"04904500","format":1024,"rawValue":"04904500","valueFormat":5},"image":{"mHeight":300,"mNativePtr":497433345344,"mWidth":300},"name":"Diet Coca-cola","quantityInPantry":3}]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you called with second activity with startActivityForResult().  Now I haven't tested it, but instead of doing that logic in onDestroy() or onPause(), try overriding onBackPressed() and see if it works. Just remember to call super.onBackPressed() instead of finish() to go back to the precious activity

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not realize there was an onBackPressed() method.  Fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the code party

First i must say logic of your issue:

You want to pass something to an activity, its just happened with intent.
when you get back to an activity with Back btn, you call onResume of this.

Now solutions :

1. you can override onBackedPressed with an intent so you can receive what you want in onResult...

2.you can change location of your code from onResult to onResume.

you can use the link below to learn more about lifeCycles in android

[Life Cycling in android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Update me in comments

Comment: I was able to get it working with the onBackPressed Method! I did not realize that was an option...thank you!